# Why is chrome giving the wrong output and firefox giving right output in this tensorflowjs code?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow

I am learning the very basics of tensorflowjs and watched a tutorial where a model is made to predict outcomes of the function y=2x-1 based on some sample data. Firefox is giving the right output but chrome isnt. chrome is giving 9.9814234 and firefox 12.8841057 for input of 7.

```
const model = tf.sequential();

model.add(tf.layers.dense({units:1, inputShape:[1]}));

model.compile({loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer:'sgd'}); 
const xs = tf.tensor2d([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6],[6,1]);
const ys = tf.tensor2d([1, 3, 5, 7, 9,11],[6,1]);


model.fit(xs,ys,{epochs:500}).then(() => {

      model.predict(tf.tensor2d([7],[1,1])).print();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the extensions that you have added to the chrome. If there are any try disable everything. If it's work try to enable one by one.

Comment: ok it did change the output but it is 11.5094776, which is still incorrect but I refreshed it and its giving 9.2016335, chrome seems to be inconsistent.

Comment: Have to disable all extensions and restarted your chrome browser? this works for me

Comment: did exactly as you asked, chrome is still inconsistent and giving wrong outputs